# Android - GridView item in center

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have GridView in one of my android application layouts. I am trying to set Item in center of Gridview but its always stay on the left side. I have searched many similar questions in StackOverflow but not got my problem solved. My XML is like below. Let me know if anyone can help me to make my GridView items in the center.

```
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/framecaregory"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/second"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridviewcategory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/lite_color"
        android:numColumns="5"
        android:visibility="gone">

    </GridView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Thanks**

Comment: You want image center inside you Gridview i am correct

Comment: do u have grid view`s item layout. if yes provide that another layout code please

Comment: @Yoni Please do not add "Android -" to the question see the [help center for tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) (in the bottom of the page) that it should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you want does not depends on grid Layout, but to its child layout which is adapted to it. First create another `layout grid_item_row.xml` and put:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/framecaregory"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="Text in the center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

After that adapt this layout to grid layout